# Why does rainbow text with KaTeX only work on firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, markdown, webkit, hugo

```
<style>
    #a-r-t {
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, lime, cyan, violet);
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: 800% 800%;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
        animation: rainbow 8s ease infinite;
    }
    @keyframes rainbow { 
        0%{background-position:0% 50%}
        50%{background-position:100% 25%}
        100%{background-position:0% 50%}
    }
</style>  
### <span id="a-r-t">$x^2$ Hello</span>
```

On Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

On Chrome/Safari:

[image]

If it's any help, I'm using Hugo and the Goldmark md renderer.

I appreciate any help!

Here is the HTML output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.7/dist/katex.min.css">
</head>

<body class="page-page" id="pagetop">

  <main class="content">
    <style>
      #a-r-t {
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, lime, cyan, violet);
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: 800% 800%;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
        animation: rainbow 8s ease infinite;
      }

      @keyframes rainbow {
        0% {
          background-position: 0% 50%
        }

        50% {
          background-position: 100% 25%
        }

        100% {
          background-position: 0% 50%
        }
      }
    </style>
    <h3 id="span-ida-r-tsum-lim_n-to-infty-x2-hellospan"><span id="a-r-t">$\sum \lim_{n \to \infty} x^2$ Hello!</span></h3>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.7/dist/katex.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.7/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      renderMathInElement(document.body, {
        delimiters: [
          { left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true },
          { left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true },
          { left: "$", right: "$", display: false },
          { left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false }
        ]
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I see when I click Ctrl + U and save the code. I don't really see why this is happening just for firefox and not chrome + safari since I thought webkit was related with chrome only.

https://jsfiddle.net/30dzgns9/

Here's a jsfiddle with this code.

Comment: Could you show us the actual rendered HTML, E.g. as seen in you browsers inspect facility?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, I added it to the question

Comment: I think you have added the source not the rendered code. The rendered code has a lot of additions from Katex. Also, on FF I see everything - the sigma, limit as well as the x squared. Do you not see these? If you remove the color:transparent you should see everything in Chrome. I would start looking from there.

Comment: Looking at the rendered code, the text which is interpreted by Katex is in nested span elements. It seems (I don't know for certain) that Firefox (using background-clip text) will somehow 'go down through the layers' but Chrome (using -webkit-background-clip text) does not. But that's not the full problem. It seems that in Chrome the special, Katex, font does not respond to the clipping even if you put the background direct on the element. (The lim gets shown, not the sigma etc). So it may be impossible to get what you want at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with Chrome:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1352821

Specifically, `position:relative;` interferes with `background-clip:text;`, and so the text has `color:transparent;` and nothing else.

It's not an exact solution, but this seems to give a similar effect. What about this?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgfm6cz8/

CSS:

```
#a-r-t *{
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-image: inherit;
    animation: inherit;
    background-size: inherit;
}
```